# Concatenate JS files using ANT (keeping a specific order)

Tags: javascript, ant

I have a bunch of js files that I need to concatenate in some specific order (becuase they are a part of an MVC implementation). How do I do this using ANT?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
<filelist id="filelist" dir="path/to/base/directory">
   <file name="util.js"/>
   <file name="commons.js" />
</filelist>

<target name="concat-all">
    <concat destfile="whatever" encoding="UTF-8" outputencoding="UTF-8" fixlastline="true">
        <filelist refid="filelist" />
    </concat>
</target>
```

We use this approach, and later resulting file is compressed via yui-compressor.

Comment: is there a way to specify some files in a specific order then all other files within the same directory? I want to load some specific libraries in a specific order but don't care about the others.

Answer (score 3):

With the [concat](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/concat.html) task, using a [filelist](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filelist.html) to preserve order.

Comment: This is the best answer in my mind.  Simple solution to a simple problem.